# Hamburger Menu Not Visible

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have pieced together a portfolio website using several tutorials and I can't figure out why the hamburger menu is not visible as it downsizes. It works fine when I take out the main content in the HTML with the sections, but if there is any main content then the burger menu does not appear.

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:wght@400;500&display=swap" rel="stylesheet"> 
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Audiowide&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">  
    <title>Portfolio</title>
</head>
<body>

    <nav>
        <div class="logo">
            <h4>Portfolio</h4>
        </div>
        <ul class="nav-links">
            <li><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="#portfolio">Portfolio</a></li>
            <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
        <div class="burger">
            <div class="line1"></div>
            <div class="line2"></div>
            <div class="line3"></div>
        </div>
    </nav>

    <main>
        <div class="about-area" id="about">
            <div class="text-part">
                <h1>About</h1>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Tempore ullam, 
                exercitationem voluptate enim nobis id quas praesentium, fugit ipsum porro omnis! 
                Illo eum exercitationem eius, quam quae deserunt? Distinctio, voluptatibus. Lorem 
                ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Repellendus non ab iure, debitis 
                minima at maxime nisi? Illum nesciunt nihil hic, provident dolorem molestias distinctio 
                optio officia suscipit nemo natus!</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="portfolio-area" id="portfolio">
            <div class="text-part">
                <h1>Portfolio</h1>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Tempore ullam, 
                exercitationem voluptate enim nobis id quas praesentium, fugit ipsum porro omnis! 
                Illo eum exercitationem eius, quam quae deserunt? Distinctio, voluptatibus. Lorem 
                ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Repellendus non ab iure, debitis 
                minima at maxime nisi? Illum nesciunt nihil hic, provident dolorem molestias distinctio 
                optio officia suscipit nemo natus!</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="contact-area" id="contact">
            <div class="text-part">
                <h1>Contact</h1>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Tempore ullam, 
                exercitationem voluptate enim nobis id quas praesentium, fugit ipsum porro omnis! 
                Illo eum exercitationem eius, quam quae deserunt? Distinctio, voluptatibus. Lorem 
                ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Repellendus non ab iure, debitis 
                minima at maxime nisi? Illum nesciunt nihil hic, provident dolorem molestias distinctio 
                optio officia suscipit nemo natus!</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </main>

<script src="app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
* {
    margin: 0px; /* Remove unwanted inherent sizing */
    padding: 0px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
}
nav {
    display: flex; /*icons are next to each other */
    justify-content: space-around; /*  */
    align-items: center; /* Center items vertically */
    min-height: 8vh;
    background-color: #0e9763;
    font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
}
.logo {
    color: rgb(226, 226, 226);
    text-transform: uppercase;
    letter-spacing: 5px;
    font-size: 20px;

}
.nav-links {
    display: flex; /* spreads out text */
    justify-content: space-around; /* using flex adds more space around the items using width */
    width: 30%;
}
.nav-links li {
    list-style: none; /* Removes bullet points */
}
.nav-links a{
    color: rgb(226, 226, 226);
    text-decoration: none; /* Removes default link colors */
    letter-spacing: 3px;
    font-size: 14px;
}
.burger {
    display: none; /* Hides the burger menu */
    cursor: pointer;
}
.burger div { /*the details of the burger menu bars design */
    width: 25px;
    height: 3px;
    background-color: rgb(226, 226, 226);
    margin: 5px;
    transition: all 0.3s ease;
}
/* Main Area Content */
.about-area, .portfolio-area, .contact-area {
    position: relative;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
    align-items: center;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    flex-direction: row;
    width: 100%;
    height: 700px;
}
.text-part {
    width: 65%;
    height: 80%;
}
h1 {
    font-size: 50px;
    font-family: 'Audiowide', cursive;

}
p {
    font-size: 24px;
    line-height: 50px;
}
.about-area {
    background: #fefefe;
}
.portfolio-area {
    background: #0e9763;
    color: #fff;
}
.contact-area {
    background: #fefefe;
}
html {
    scroll-behavior: smooth;
}
a:hover {
    color: #000;
}
/* Quick fix breakpoint between max size and hamburger menu trigger */
@media screen and (max-width:1024px){
    .nav-links {
        width: 60%;
    }
}
@media screen and (max-width:768px){
    body {
        overflow: hidden;
    }
    .nav-links {
        position: absolute;
        right: 0px;
        height: 92vh;
        top: 8vh;
        background-color: #0e9763;
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        align-items: center;
        width: 50%;
        transform: translateX(100%); /* Moves content off screen */
        transition: transform 0.5s ease-in;
    }
    .nav-links li {
        opacity: 0;
    }
    .burger {
        display: block;
    }
}
.nav-active {
    transform: translateX(0%); /* When button is clicked the nav gets the transform */
}

/* Nav animation */
@keyframes navLinkFade{
    from{
        opacity: 0;
        transform: translateX(50px);
    }
    to {
        opacity: 1;
        transform: translateX(0px);
    }
}
.toggle .line1 {
    transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(-5px,6px);
}
.toggle .line2 {
    opacity: 0;
}
.toggle .line3 {
    transform: rotate(45deg) translate(-5px,-6px);
}
```

JS:

```
const navSlide = () => { //navSlide is = to an anonymous function
    const burger = document.querySelector('.burger');
    const nav = document.querySelector('.nav-links');
    const navLinks = document.querySelectorAll('.nav-links li'); 

    burger.addEventListener('click',() => { //on click run a function
        //Toggle Nav
        nav.classList.toggle('nav-active');
        //Animate Links
        navLinks.forEach((link, index) => {
            if (link.style.animation){
                link.style.animation = ''
            } else {
                link.style.animation = `navLinkFade 0.5s ease forwards ${index / 7 + 0.5}s`
            }       
        });
        //Burger Animation
        burger.classList.toggle('toggle');

    });
}
//Invoke function
navSlide();
```

Here is a link to the codepen:
https://codepen.io/justadirtgrub/pen/NWGJrde

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add `z-index` css property to class `.nav-active` to show up in front of main content

```js
const navSlide = () => {
  //navSlide is = to an anonymous function
  const burger = document.querySelector(".burger");
  const nav = document.querySelector(".nav-links");
  const navLinks = document.querySelectorAll(".nav-links li");

  burger.addEventListener("click", () => {
    //on click run a function
    //Toggle Nav
    nav.classList.toggle("nav-active");
    //Animate Links
    navLinks.forEach((link, index) => {
      if (link.style.animation) {
        link.style.animation = "";
      } else {
        link.style.animation = `navLinkFade 0.5s ease forwards ${
          index / 7 + 0.5
        }s`;
      }
    });
    //Burger Animation
    burger.classList.toggle("toggle");
  });
};
//Invoke function
navSlide();
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0px; /* Remove unwanted inherent sizing */
  padding: 0px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: "Poppins", sans-serif;
}
nav {
  display: flex; /*icons are next to each other */
  justify-content: space-around; /*  */
  align-items: center; /* Center items vertically */
  min-height: 8vh;
  background-color: #0e9763;
  font-family: "Poppins", sans-serif;
}
.logo {
  color: rgb(226, 226, 226);
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 5px;
  font-size: 20px;
}
.nav-links {
  display: flex; /* spreads out text */
  justify-content: space-around; /* using flex adds more space around the items using width */
  width: 30%;
}
.nav-links li {
  list-style: none; /* Removes bullet points */
}
.nav-links a {
  color: rgb(226, 226, 226);
  text-decoration: none; /* Removes default link colors */
  letter-spacing: 3px;
  font-size: 14px;
}
.burger {
  display: none; /* Hides the burger menu */
  cursor: pointer;
}
.burger div {
  /*the details of the burger menu bars design */
  width: 25px;
  height: 3px;
  background-color: rgb(226, 226, 226);
  margin: 5px;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
}
/* Main Area Content */
.about-area,
.portfolio-area,
.contact-area {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-direction: row;
  width: 100%;
  height: 700px;
}
.text-part {
  width: 65%;
  height: 80%;
}
h1 {
  font-size: 50px;
  font-family: "Audiowide", cursive;
}
p {
  font-size: 24px;
  line-height: 50px;
}
.about-area {
  background: #fefefe;
}
.portfolio-area {
  background: #0e9763;
  color: #fff;
}
.contact-area {
  background: #fefefe;
}
html {
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
}
a:hover {
  color: #000;
}
/* Quick fix breakpoint between max size and hamburger menu trigger */
@media screen and (max-width: 1024px) {
  .nav-links {
    width: 60%;
  }
}
@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  body {
    overflow: hidden;
  }
  .nav-links {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0px;
    height: 92vh;
    top: 8vh;
    background-color: #0e9763;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    width: 50%;
    transform: translateX(100%); /* Moves content off screen */
    transition: transform 0.5s ease-in;
  }
  .nav-links li {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  .burger {
    display: block;
  }
}
.nav-active {
  transform: translateX(0%);
  z-index: 100; /* When button is clicked the nav gets the transform */
}

/* Nav animation */
@keyframes navLinkFade {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: translateX(50px);
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: translateX(0px);
  }
}
.toggle .line1 {
  transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(-5px, 6px);
}
.toggle .line2 {
  opacity: 0;
}
.toggle .line3 {
  transform: rotate(45deg) translate(-5px, -6px);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<head>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:wght@400;500&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Audiowide&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <title>Portfolio</title>
</head>

<body>

  <nav>
    <div class="logo">
      <h4>Portfolio</h4>
    </div>
    <ul class="nav-links">
      <li><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
      <li><a href="#portfolio">Portfolio</a></li>
      <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div class="burger">
      <div class="line1"></div>
      <div class="line2"></div>
      <div class="line3"></div>
    </div>
  </nav>

  <main>
    <div class="about-area" id="about">
      <div class="text-part">
        <h1>About</h1>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Tempore ullam,
          exercitationem voluptate enim nobis id quas praesentium, fugit ipsum porro omnis!
          Illo eum exercitationem eius, quam quae deserunt? Distinctio, voluptatibus. Lorem
          ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Repellendus non ab iure, debitis
          minima at maxime nisi? Illum nesciunt nihil hic, provident dolorem molestias distinctio
          optio officia suscipit nemo natus!</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="portfolio-area" id="portfolio">
      <div class="text-part">
        <h1>Portfolio</h1>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Tempore ullam,
          exercitationem voluptate enim nobis id quas praesentium, fugit ipsum porro omnis!
          Illo eum exercitationem eius, quam quae deserunt? Distinctio, voluptatibus. Lorem
          ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Repellendus non ab iure, debitis
          minima at maxime nisi? Illum nesciunt nihil hic, provident dolorem molestias distinctio
          optio officia suscipit nemo natus!</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="contact-area" id="contact">
      <div class="text-part">
        <h1>Contact</h1>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Tempore ullam,
          exercitationem voluptate enim nobis id quas praesentium, fugit ipsum porro omnis!
          Illo eum exercitationem eius, quam quae deserunt? Distinctio, voluptatibus. Lorem
          ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Repellendus non ab iure, debitis
          minima at maxime nisi? Illum nesciunt nihil hic, provident dolorem molestias distinctio
          optio officia suscipit nemo natus!</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </main>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Any suggestion as to why I can't scroll down the page once the hamburger menu has been toggled?

Comment: you cannot scroll because you have added body {
    overflow: hidden;
  } in media query for 768px or less.   So it wont scroll.   Remove it to make scroll